# Best way to split the array into smaller chunks - C programming

Tags: c, arrays

What would be the best way to split an array of let say size 2000 into chunks of 250 elements.
array[2000] --> split into chunks of 250 elements, 8 sub arrays.
Thanks.

Comment: Define "best" and "split". I would leave it as is.

Comment: Very likely this is a display problem, not a storage problem.  Treat it as such.

Comment: Depends on whether you want to allocate new memory and copy your arrays data to that new memory, or use pointers to reinterpret your original array as multiple sub-arrays, in-place.

Comment: The marked duplicate is by no means a duplicate.  There the question is about why the solution crashes, not how to do the split.

Comment: The best way could be *not to split it at all*. Instead of using arr2[15], you would use origArray[2*250+15]. With the appropriate use of macros, you could have *both* at the same time.

Is this an allocation problem somehow? Is it that you need at most 256 elements in a single chunk? You should explain *what* you're trying to accomplish, and possibly even *why*.

Comment: You should be clearer about what you are tying to achieve and about the data in question.  It is by no means completely clear what you mean by "split", and it looks rather like an X-Y question, where you have determined Y is a solution to problem X but you cannot make Y work, so you are asking about Y, when clearly you should ask about X.

Comment: @LSerni : Your comment seems to bare little relationship to the question - different sizes, different array names and a completely ambiguous explanation.  It would be better perhaps to post an answer; if you feel that there is not yet enough information for an answer, then you should not attempt to answer in a comment.

Answer (score 3):

Given:

```
#define ARRAY_SIZE 2000
#define CHUNKS 8
#define CHUNK_SIZE = (ARRAY_SIZE / CHUNKS)
atype array[ARRAY_SIZE] ;
```

then:

```
atype* chunks[CHUNKS] ;
for( int i = 0; i < CHUNKS; i++ )
{
    chunks[i] = &array[i * CHUNK_SIZE] ;
}
```

`chunks` can then be accessed *as if* it were a two dimensional array `chunks[8][250]`.  However there are some important differences.

It may make more sense in fact to define the array `chunks[8][250]`, then create a *single* pointer `array` to refer to the combined chunks:

```
atype chunks[CHUNKS][CHUNK_SIZE] ;
atype* array = (atype*)chunks ;
```

then instead `chunks` is a true two dimensional array, while `array` can be accessed *as if* it were an array `array[2000]` - but again it is *not* identical.  The advantage here is clearly the simpler initialisation - it does not required a loop.

The difference between the two is:

[image]

and importantly, in the first:

```
sizeof(array) == sizeof(atype * ARRAY_SIZE)
sizeof(chunks) == sizeof( atype* * CHUNKS)
```

while in the second:

```
sizeof(array) == sizeof(atype*)
sizeof(chunks) == sizeof( atype * CHUNKS * CHUNK_SIZE)
```

These distinctions are important if you are to be copying or moving the data.

Answer (score 0):

One can do it easily using pointers. Here is the detailed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int raw_array_size=2000;  //Specify size of the large array  
    int chunk_size=250;  //Specify chunk size
    int chunk_num=0;  //Keep track of the chunk being processed
    int raw_array[raw_array_size];  //Source array
    int chunk_array[chunk_size];  //Desitination chunk array
    int total_chunks,i;
    int *raw_ptr = raw_array;   // Pointer to source_arr
    int *chunk_ptr  = chunk_array;     // Pointer to chunk_arr
    int *end_ptr_raw_for_second_last_chunk, *end_ptr_raw_for_last_chunk;  //Pointers to the end of source array for second last and last chunks
    
    total_chunks=(raw_array_size/chunk_size) + 1;  //Total no. of chunks
    printf("total chunks=%d\n", total_chunks);
    end_ptr_raw_for_second_last_chunk = &raw_array[(total_chunks-1)*chunk_size - 1]; //Point to the correct address 
    end_ptr_raw_for_last_chunk = &raw_array[raw_array_size-1];
    
    //Fill up source array
    for(i=0;i<raw_array_size;i++)
    raw_array[i]=i;
    
    
    //Cpying to the chunk array in a loop upto the second last chunk
    while(raw_ptr <= end_ptr_raw_for_second_last_chunk)
    {
        chunk_ptr= &chunk_array[0];  //Pointing to the begining of the chunk array
        for(i=0; i<chunk_size; i++)  //Copying each element for a particular chunk
        {
            *chunk_ptr = *raw_ptr;  
            // Increment raw_ptr and chunk_ptr
            raw_ptr++;
            chunk_ptr++;
        }
        chunk_num++;
        printf("For %dth chunk\n", chunk_num);
        for(i=0; i<chunk_size; i++)
            printf("%d\t", chunk_array[i]);
        printf("\n");
    }

    chunk_ptr= &chunk_array[0]; 
    //Cpying to the chunk array in a loop for the last chunk
    while(raw_ptr <= end_ptr_raw_for_last_chunk)
    {
        *chunk_ptr = *raw_ptr;
        // Increment raw_ptr and dest_ptr
        raw_ptr++;
        chunk_ptr++;
    }
     //Fill up the remaining elements with 0
    while(chunk_ptr <= &chunk_array[chunk_size-1])
    {
        *chunk_ptr = 0;
        chunk_ptr++;
    }
    
    chunk_num++;
    printf("For %dth chunk\n", chunk_num);
    for(i=0; i<chunk_size; i++)
    printf("%d\t", chunk_array[i]);
    
    printf("\n");
    
        

    return 0;
}
```